# How is three phase power delivered and used in Malta?

Tags: electrical

I currently live in Canada with a plan to move to Malta.

Here three phase means an oven connector like a NEMA 14-50. The NEMA 5-15 household connectors are single phase.

The BS 1363 (Type G) plugs and sockets used in the UK and Malta also have hot-neutral-ground prongs.

However, Enemalta has this to say:

> If your household demand exceeds 40A, then you can apply for addition of load to transition to three phase supply through the ARMS website. An authorized electrician will to make the required modifications to the installation. You do not need to discontinue the single phase supply prior to the addition of load.

I am *confused*. Like, very very confused. What happens to all household appliances? Surely you are not going to replace every socket with some industrial monstrosity but if they still use the same three prong connector, well, how can I use the added electricity?

Comment: If I understand it a tiny bit, they separate the three phases, so you have part of the house on one phase and parts on the other phases.  The large device users would get two phases(something like our 240, but maybe 208v).  Our nema 14-50 is split phase combining the two 120v wires for 240.

Comment: NEMA 14-50 is not three phase, we don't usually have 3 phase in Canadian homes. 2 phase 120V/240V. Please better clarify what is confusing you. Do you want 3 phase in Malta?

Comment: @crip659 that's the answer I was looking for, thanks. Should I delete this question? Do I want three phase? Not particularly but I will need more than 40A and this is how Enemalta delivers it.

Comment: Would not delete, it might help someone else and one of the experts to answer fully.  Would use Malta appliances instead of trying to save money by moving/shipping your Canadian appliances.  The power systems are usually different enough to cause problems with most, some are made for different systems, but not that many.  Would try Malta power system first, might find 40 amps to be enough.  We kind of use power hogs in our homes.

Comment: Malta is 230V per phase, 400V across any 2 of the 3 phases. All appliances must be rated 230V 50Hz. The fact that parts of the house are on different phases means nothing for the voltage, only for load balancing. But if you have a workshop, EV or heat you can get/use 3-phase.

Comment: Of course, I will buy new appliances. I get it now. Does either of you want to write an answer I can accept? "part of the house on one phase and parts on the other phases"... "The fact that parts of the house are on different phases means nothing for the voltage" forms a very clear picture that was not at all clear before.

Comment: ok but please edit your question to more clearly define it. I sort of reverse engineered what you were asking from the comments....

Comment: 3 phases are good for motors, so they do not need start capacitor to start running, 50 Hz is bad for 60 Hz motors, light bulbs do not care

Comment: I'm currently having a house in Malta renovated, including a complete electrical installation.  One of the decisions we made early is not to use gas for cooking or water heating, both of which are relatively common in Malta. @chx you have it right in one of your comments - you WILL want more than a 40A service and 3-phase is how Enemalta deliver it.  Two ovens, induction hob, water heater (maybe 3 or 4), a/c, computers, etc, etc ... our calculations suggested a peak draw of about 38A - no headroom, and we don't want to pay for an upgrade in a year's time.

Comment: It's really no different from what you have now.  You have two feeds of 120 volts and your various circuits are on one or the other.  In Malta you'll have two or three feeds of 230 volts and your various circuits will be on one or the other.  The main difference is that in Canada you take advantage of the phase difference and provide 240 volts to larger appliances.  In Malta you don't use phase to phase power in typical residential.  Instead high power appliances just split their loads across multiple phases if they are available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You won't be bringing appliances over anyway

North American appliances are not made to run on European power and vice versa. The voltages are not compatible and the AC power frequency is not compatible.  Most large appliances are inexpensive enough to not be worth shipping.

- Dryers and ranges won't work because they need 120V.
- Water heaters are not valuable enough to tear out of a house and ship.
- The AC power frequency is wrong for our air conditioners, and they have better technology anyway.
- Furnaces are not compatible.
- They use [type 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_2_connector) EV plugs, not type 1 or Tesla.

### North American *Split Phase* is not 3-phase

> Here three phase means an oven connector like a NEMA 14-50.

That's incorrect. We don't have 3-phase in typical homes.

A NEMA 14-50 outlet is a **split-phase** outlet appropriate for 120/240V split-phase. Split-phase is not similar to 3-phase. Split-phase is 240V single-phase with both wires hot. It is center-tapped, providing a neutral and making both hot wires 120V to ground.

It's not 2-phase.  It's a single phase with a center tap.

If you're still not tracking, [try this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMmUoZh3Hq4).

### Europe is functionally single-phase

The Europeans do not use a system anything like this. They also deliver two wires to a home with 240V between them, except there is no third "neutral" wire in the middle.  In fact, neutral is one of the two wires. **It is that simple**.

In Europe all loads connect between the hot wire and neutral. No crazy 4-pin plugs are needed.  This works because being twice the voltage, each circuit can deliver a lot more power. Here are basic sockets.

[image]

That's why their kettles are faster.

Now... Behind the curtain (or rather: up at the pole, distribution on your block is coming from a 3-phase transformer making 3 phases of 230V.  Each house gets 1 phase, so it doesn't matter to the homeowner.

However they do not like thick wires in Europe, so when you need more power than a typical service gets (e.g. 63A), they won't give fatter wires - they'll give you a second phase.   Still, all your appliances are single-phase, you'll just put them on one phase or another.  They are still 230V loads.

Some countries almost never deliver more than one phase. Other countries give 2-3 phases to just about everyone.

A few loads, including cookers / hobs / ranges, have 2-3 "sections" of the appliance.  You can put all 3 sections on the same phase if you want.  However, if you have 2 phases or all 3, you can put the sections on different phases.

In rare cases, you have appliances that take and use all 3 phases. That might be a commercial grade motor or a kiln. Probably the #1 application for 3-phase is [EV charging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_2_connector); Europe has a different "Type 2/Mennekes"  EV socket with 5 large wires instead of 3. The extra 2 are for the other phases.

Most appliances large enough to be 3-phase are instead hardwired.

Comment: While 230V/400V is the most common supply system in Europe, the details vary a lot. Here in the UK it's rare to see three phase in a house. OTOH in the Netherlands they have 3 phase systems as small as 3x25A, maybe even smaller and they have cookers designed to spread the load across multiple phases.

Comment: and while the type 2 connector supports 3 phase EV charging, a lot of vehicles only ave single phase chargers,

Comment: @PeterGreen yeah, that's the problem we're finding in the US. The #1 level 2 charge rate is 32A using the "free" travel EVSE. 48A is uncommon and 80A is almost unheard of. Like Alec says, 30A is plenty. The charger is on the car so why add cost/weight of a >32A charger? Same logic would apply to 3-phase charging. For those "But SOMETIMES" cases there is DC fast charging, and modest scale DC fast charging is affordable and even supported directly by J1772 and Mennekes *without the CCS pins*.

Comment: I wish we'd go to Tesla and say "Please design a full-power version of your elegant plug" and we will make that the world standard and that's that. Sooner we do that, the better.  3-phase chargers can simply rectify or convert to an intermediate DC voltage, the onboard charger doesn't care if it gets AC or DC.   Tesla is claiming "we already did" but I think they are claiming more ampacity than it's really capable of.

Answer (score 4):

### Malta is 230V 50Hz

Malta is 230V per phase, 400V across any 2 of the 3 phases.

All appliances must be rated 230V 50Hz.

### For most uses, 3-Phase is still 230V

The fact that parts of the house are on different phases means nothing for the voltage, only for load balancing.

You will not have 3-phase in every socket througout the house. But if you have a workshop, EV or heat you can get/use 3-phase wired there.

### Canada/US is 2-Phase 120V/240V

Regarding the NEMA 14-50 socket in North America, it has 4 slots but it is not three phase. The 4 slots are Neutral, Live 1, Live 2, and Ground.

We don't usually have 3 phase in Canadian or US homes, but rather 2 phases, delivering twice 120V at two opposing phase. This results in 240V across the two opposing phases.

### Why Higher Voltage 240V and 400V?

The **240V** Canada/US voltage allows higher loading with smaller diameter wiring, compared to the same power consumption with the 120V voltage.

This saves on wiring costs, and the lower current for the same power results in lower resistive losses throughout the wiring.

The same "higher voltage / lower current" reasoning applies to 3-phase systems: the phase to neutral voltage in Malta is 230V, and the higher phase-phase voltage of **400V** allows higher loads at smaller diameter wiring (lower installation cost) and with less losses in the wiring.

### Who needs 3 phases?

A further benefit of 3 phase over 2 phase (irrespective of the voltage) is that very high powered (industrial) motors have better efficiency and RPM control when supplied with 3 phase.

This is not a factor for today's electronically controlled household appliances. However, in the past, homes that were supplied with 3 phases for power reasons could take advantage of this and connect appliances with 3 phase motors, like 3-phase washing machines, dryers or dishwashers.

Therefore, while a house may be wired with 3 phases, individual sockets throughout will still be 230V.

In some special locations, such as perhaps a garage or workshop, there will be 3-phase sockets to take advantage of the higher voltage for higher power (e.g. EV charger, welder, kiln), or to take advantage of the 3 phases for an industrial sized motor (e.g. hoist, ventilation).

In some other locations, such as a kitchen or furnace room, there may be 3 phases to deliver heat at high power with high voltage.

Comment: Having 3-phase available is either a Very Good Thing (if you do certain types of hobbies or work) or something you won't notice.

Comment: I remember having 3-phase sockets for washing machines and ovens when I first moved to Germany. Now everything works on normal sockets, which is much more convenient.

Comment: indeed @RedSonja, https://tff-forum.de/t/welche-haushaltsgeraete-benoetigen-drei-phasen/5251

Answer (score 3):

You're confused because you learned wrong about what's going on in Canada.

1. NEMA 14-50 is 2-phase, not 3-phase
2. Almost all houses in Canada are wired 2-phase. But you still get to use NEMA 5 single phase appliances, do you?

It's very simple. In Canada, when you want 115V you connect phase-to-neutral using small NEMA 5 socket. When you want 230V you connect phase-to-phase using big NEMA 14 socket.

Having your house wired for 2-phases means you get **BOTH** types of sockets, enabling you to use BOTH kinds of appliances.

3 phase system is slightly different, but to end user nothing changes: When you want 230V you connect phase-to-neutral. When you want 400V you connect phase-to-phase-to-phase.

> What happens to all household appliances?

Nothing.

> Surely you are not going to replace every socket with some industrial monstrosity but if they still use the same three prong connector, well, how can I use the added electricity?

Same as in Canada: You get MORE of single-phase sockets plus ADDITIONAL multi-phase sockets in your kitchen and garage.

> An authorized electrician will to make the required modifications to the installation

That means that your house gets rewired, to some degree. This part can get expensive.

As others have mentioned, unless you want to run industrial or agricultural machinery, 230V is enough. It even might be enough to charge an electric car, just slower. Had you need 3-phase, you'd already know it.

Disclaimer: 110V and 115V means same thing. 220V and 230V means same thing. 380V and 400V means same thing. All within acceptable margin.